# Find info from drop box form in Python

Tags: python

```
<p>
<select name='type'>
<option>Only Names</option>
<option>Only Numbers</option>
</select>
</p>
```

If I were to make a Python script, and search for names if Only Names were selected, how would I go about doing that? Like what would I enter in my python script? Example of what is in my head right now:

```
if form == Only Names:
   print stuff
```

Adding more info at the request of comments:

```
    import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
from file import *

f = File("lists.data")

if f.exists() == True:
    f.startRead()
    list = f.read()
    f.close()

    print "<h1>Catalog</h1>"
    print "<ul>"

    sequel2 = variables.find ("2")
    sequel3 = variables.find ("3")
    superheroMan = variables.find ("man")
    superheroWoman = variables.find ("woman")
    superheroBoy = variables.find ("person")

    for variable in list:
        if NEED TO KNOW THIS PART


        print "<li>" + variable + "</li>"

    print "</ul>" 

else:
    print "<p>Error: No saved data found.</p>"
```

And here is my form:

```
                <p>Lists to display:</p>
                <div>
                    <select name='type'>
                        <option>Only Names</option>
                        <option>Only Numbers</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  

                <p><input type='submit' value='Display'></p>
        </form>
```

Comment: This requires a bit more info to answer. What is the actual input to the python script? What should it output? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make such a python script, you need to find a way of connecting your form to the python code. Since the code should refer to the state of the form, it needs to know the state of a file open in a browser.

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. Use HTTP to transfer requests to a python server operating in the background. I would recommend [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [cherrypy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) for that task.
2. Have the code run inside the browser - but that requires the code to be javascript, not python. Javascript is very easy to learn, and you might want to consider that, too.

Comment: This is for a computer course at school, but the professor did not explain this part of the assignment. I have no option but to use Python as it will be worth 0 marks if it is anything else.

Is there some other way that I could make different lists based on what data my drop box gives?

Comment: In that case, ask your professor / other students, in which way does the data get from the form to the python function. I guess that you already have an HTTP server set up?

Comment: Yes. The server is up, and other python scripts have worked well. The only part I am stuck at is trying to get information from a value that is received from a drop box. Normally, I use open forms where users type in words. I have never before had to get information from a form that is a drop box.

Comment: I am not sure about your web framework. Try printing out dir(variables), and see which variables are available. There is probably one called "type", which is the one you want.

Comment: It is not showing me the variables properly because of multiple python scripts that are linking together to make this script...